# Rewrite Cond based on query string parameter - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a query string that looks like this:

```
 widget.com/?id=1555&a1=chosen&w=hello
```

I am trying to modify this code:

```
 SetEnvIf Referer "^https?://(.*)/" myref=$1
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !corz.org [NC]
 RewriteRule . - [cookie=original-referer:%{ENV:myref}:.%{HTTP_HOST}:1440:/]
```

But instead of using the Referer as the RewriteCond I want to determine if a1=chosen

based on the QueryString from widget.com/?id=1555&a1=chosen&w=hello

My current code looks like this:

```
 SetEnvIf Referer "^http?://(.*)/" myref=$1
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a1=chosen 
 RewriteRule . - [cookie=source:%{ENV:myref}:.%{HTTP_HOST}:1440:/]
```

I think the problem is in the way I have the rewrite cond for the query string param. I've literally spent 12 hours searching and trying different regex expressions.

I also want to make sure that if the a1=chosen is absent from this expression, or perhaps has a different value, then no cookie is created.

Thank you for taking a look at this.

I just want to get it to work. lol

I can get the original code to work and set a cookie from .htaccess, but I havve literally searched for 12 hours on this to no avail.

Also, is there a way to make sure that if someone already has a cookie that a new one is not generated?